# How would I make an object transparent where light is not touching it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

How would I make an object transparent where light is not diffused off of it (in diffuse shader)? I have no idea how I would do this. I am using Cycles.

Comment: hey! what you need is the Light Path Node: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/light_path.html look into it on YouTube. sorry i can't help you better right now (working).

Comment: Ok. How would I use that to do what I want? I cant find anything

Comment: try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTFxyNzI5EE

Comment: I watched it, but I still cant figure out how I would use it to make the unlit side of my object transparent...